# Why is webpack trying to bundle my test files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, webpack

I have two main directories in my project: "src" and "specs".
The entrypoint of my webpack configuration is set to a file within src. Also the context of the webpack config is set to the src directory. I have a postinstall hook in my package.json which bundles the app into a dist folder whenever the package is installed via "npm install". This also means that the devDependencies are not installed and that is what causes my npm install to fail. Apparently webpack tries to process the files in specs which it cannot do because the devDependencies are not installed.

Any idea why webpack thinks it should process the files in the specs directory?

Here is my complete webpack config:

```
const path = require("path");
const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");
const NODE_ENV = "development";

const client = {
  entry: path.join(__dirname, "src", "browser_sdk", "index.ts"),
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "browser_sdk"),
  target: "web",
  mode: NODE_ENV,
  devtool: "source-map",
  watch: false,
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "client.js",
    library: {
      type: "umd",
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: "ts-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules.*\.js$/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"],
  },
  externals: {
    "pg-native": "require('pg-native')"
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: false,
  },
};

const server = {
  entry: path.join(__dirname, "src", "server", "index.ts"),
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "server"),
  mode: NODE_ENV,
  target: "node",
  externals: [nodeExternals(), 'pg-native'],
  watch: false,
  devtool: "source-map",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "server.js",
    library: {
      type: "umd",
    },
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".js"],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: "ts-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules.*\.js$/,
      },
    ],
  },
};

module.exports = [server, client];
```

Comment: Another funny thing is, when the package is installed into another project, it will be placed into the node_modules folder of this project. So a plain exclude: /node_modules/ will exclude all files of the project because the whole project is within a node_modules folder

Comment: That information needs to be in your question post, not down here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following config fixed my problems. I used `transpileOnly` to prevent the specs directory is bundled and I wrote a custom exclude handler to prevent node_module is bundled.

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: {
          loader: "ts-loader",
          options: {
            transpileOnly: true
          },
        },
        exclude: (e) => {
          let file = e.replace(__dirname, '.');

          return file.match(/node_modules/)
        }
      },
    ],
  },
```